# Jquery works only once

Tags: jquery

The jquery code goes through a nested list.  Once it loads, it works well once (switches classes), but a full click through it won't repeat.  The class switches a triangle bullet from left facing to downwards.  I can't figure how to get it to repeat.  Any help much appreciated.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".list-year").click(function() {        
    jQuery(this).removeClass('list-year li');
    jQuery(this).addClass('list-year-down li');  
    jQuery('.list-month').toggle( function() {
        jQuery(".list-year-down").click(function() {
            jQuery(this).removeClass('list-year-down li');
            jQuery(this).addClass('list-year li'); 
        });
    });        
  });
});
```

Comment: better to use toggleClass

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
jQuery(".list-year").on('click',(function() {
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still only works once.  It will toggle the list up and down no problem, but it won't swap the classes.

Answer (score 1):

Attach an event handler to a parent element using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), and pass the selector as an argument.

Try:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(document).on('click, '.list-year', function() {        
    jQuery(this).removeClass('list-year li');
    jQuery(this).addClass('list-year-down li');  
    jQuery('.list-month').toggle( function() {
        jQuery(".list-year-down").click(function() {
            jQuery(this).removeClass('list-year-down li');
            jQuery(this).addClass('list-year li'); 
        });
    });        
  });
});
```

Also note that for jQuery 1.9.1 +, toggle() won't work as before...

Answer (score 0):

Because you remove the .class that you put the click handler on, THEN you remove it - you loose that binding. Do what Dipesh above suggests use ".on" for jQuery 1.7 or greater, else you can use ".live" (deprecated).

Answer (score 0):

try Toggling the class `.toggleClass()`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".list-year").click(function() {        
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('list-year-down');
    jQuery('.list-month').toggle( function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      jQuery(".list-year-down").click(function() {
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('list-year-down'); 
      });
    });        
  });
});
```

on Default put this class to lis: `list-year li`

Answer (score 0):

try :D

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".list-year").click(function() {        

    jQuery(this).toggleClass('list-year list-year-down');

  });
});
```